# canvas not drawing correctly

Tags: java, android, canvas, draw

I have a class GameCanvas extending View, and I use it in my xml layout:

```
public class GameCanvas extends View {

private Canvas canvas;
private Paint painter;

public GameCanvas(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(ctx, attrs);

    painter = new Paint();
    painter.setAntiAlias(true);
    painter.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    painter.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    painter.setStrokeWidth(5);
}

@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.canvas = canvas;

    // JUST AN EXAMPLE

    int w = 50;

    // This should draw a table, it doesn't work.
    for(int i = 0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<3; ++j)
        {
            int x = j*w;
            int y = i*w;

            canvas.drawRect(x,y,w,w, painter);

        }
    }

    // This is drawn, this works!
    canvas.drawRect(50,50,100,100, painter);

    // This doesn't work
    canvas.drawRect(300,450,100,100, painter);

}
}
```

And my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/game_bottombar"
            android:id="@+id/game_canvas_container">

            // (Hiding my ID)
            <com.---.---.---.GameCanvas
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The canvas works, I see it on my screen, I tried changing the background color to RED or GREEN, and it works and fills the whole area.

Furthermore, one line works:

```
canvas.drawRect(50,50,100,100, painter);
```

Apparently when I draw a rect in coordinates below 100 or 150 it works, but if my rect has a size of 400 it also works and the rect fills all of the space, so the problem isn't the canvas size.

Debugger says my canvas size is: 720 x 952

******* UPDATE - SOLUTION ***************/

I was using width and height instead of right and bottom:

```
drawRect( left, top, right, bottom);
```

Where right and bottom is the distance from the end of the rectangle to the end of the canvas.

I don't know why this is made this way, it's very unpleasant to work. I don't know if there's already a method in the canvas, I didn't found it so I wrote it myself:

```
public void DrawRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+w, y+h, painter);
}
```

I know it's quite simple, but I prefer using this.

Comment: This line `canvas.drawRect(300,450,100,100, painter)` looks weird to me. The 5 params are: left, top, right, bottom and Paint. Looks like you are passing `width` and `height` instead of `right` and `bottom`

Comment: Oh you're right! I will update the question and post the solution I found.